# Docker containers fails to 'inherit' the instance profile of the host ec2 even though IAM is assigned

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, stack

```
Docker containers 'fails' to 'inherit' the instance profile of the host ec2 even though IAM is assigned.
But it will work smoothly if I re-deploy the docker stack services.

Error log:

Request: POST /exports
** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(ExAws.Config.Aut`enter code here`hCache, {:refresh_config, %{access_key_id: [{:system, "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"}, :instance_role] http_client: ExAws.Request.Hackney, json_codec: Poison, region: "ap-southeast-1", retries: [max_attempts: 10, base_backoff_in_ms: 10, max_backoff_in_ms: 10000], scheme: "https://", secret_access_key: [{:system, "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"}, :instance_role]}}, 30000)
```

IAM has got full permissions even though I get the error from docker containers. But if I re-deploy stack it will work well.

```
** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
** (RuntimeError) Instance Meta Error: {:error, %{reason: :connect_timeout}}
You tried to access the AWS EC2 instance meta, but it could not be reached.
This happens most often when trying to access it from your local computer,
which happens when environment variables are not set correctly prompting
ExAws to fallback to the Instance Meta.
Please check your key config and make sure they're configured correctly:
For Example:

ExAws.Config.new(:s3)
ExAws.Config.new(:dynamodb)

(ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/instance_meta.ex:26: ExAws.InstanceMeta.request/2
(ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/instance_meta.ex:58: ExAws.InstanceMeta.instance_role_credentials/1
(ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/instance_meta.ex:64: ExAws.InstanceMeta.security_credentials/1
(ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/config/auth_cache.ex:58: ExAws.Config.AuthCache.refresh_config/2
(ex_aws) lib/ex_aws/config/auth_cache.ex:33: ExAws.Config.AuthCache.handle_call/3
(stdlib) gen_server.erl:615: :gen_server.try_handle_call/4
(stdlib) gen_server.erl:647: :gen_server.handle_msg/5
(stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```